# How to make font-awesome glow css

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have used font-awesome of

```
<i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i>
```

It shows a circle with red outline. I want it to become full red circle and blink.

Sorry I am not a front end developer so I couldn't think of its solution.

what I tried to do is

```
.text-red
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

but this didn't work. Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: use css animation for that.

Comment: Many pardons, mate, but I am like very weak in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said you could try `css animation`, already using `background` you can change `background-color`, now using `opacity` you can `create` that `blinking effect` as below,

```css
.fa{
  color:red;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation:op 3s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes op{
0%{
  opacity:0;
}
50%{
  opacity:1;
}
100%{
  opacity:0;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i>
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much! This is what I wanted!

Comment: Welcome @Alen :-), but do search for css animation, see you changed background of icons, now just using animation we got that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can Just Use css rules `background:red, border-radius:100%` and `color:red;`

```css
.text-red
{
  color:red;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" >
<i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i>
```